# Instagram Graph API get other accounts info

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Good morning, I am a student of computer engineering, and I am developing my final degree project which is to create a client that receives and displays basic data from other public companies. I'm testing the endpoints and I have encountered several problems. From what I have read, to get the comments of a post from a public business account, we need the permission of that account. When I try to access the get with the ig-media id, I get the error:

Unsupported get request. Object with ID '17888069216935917' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

code: 100  error_subcode:33

What I don't understand is why the first day it did let me get all the comments of the posts, also the replies of the comments, and even the collaborators of the post. Can it be that the first day I had all the permissions and then I have deleted them? Could you confirm me that as for the information I can get from other companies, I can only get what business_discovery offers?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Permissions you granted to your app once, don't "disappear" on their own. Whether you might have _deliberately_ removed some again, we can't possibly know. But you can put your token through the access token debugger tool, that will tell you what granted permissions it contains.

Comment: First of all, thank you for responding. Regarding the permissions, I have set the 33 permissions that the Graph Explorer API allows me, so I understand that it is not a matter of not having selected some permission, but that I do not have access to that information...

Comment: _"Could you confirm me that as for the information I can get from other companies, I can only get what business_discovery offers?"_ - yes. As https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/business-discovery#getting-basic-metrics-on-media explicitly states, you can get some basic metrics about the latest media via the account ID, but - _"Note that this does not grant you permission to access media objects directly — performing a GET on any returned IG Media will fail due to insufficient permissions."_

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for solving my doubt. I had read that, but I didn't know if there was any way to access that information, because as I said, the first day it left me. But now it is clear to me that it is not possible. Thank you very much for taking your time CBroe.